# Why mode can't be set while reading files using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose if we are reading a file: Mode is set (r, w, a, r+, w+, a+)

```
with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.write("hello")
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
```

Question:
In above program, csv file is read through pandas but why mode (r, w, a, r+, w+, a+) is not considered.

Comment: Because `read_csv` only reads, e.g. there's probably an implicit `r` set underneath the hood. Could be this line (haven't stepped through the code): [pandas/io/parsers/readers.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e8093ba372f9adfe79439d90fe74b0b5b6dea9d6/pandas/io/parsers/readers.py#L1211)

Comment: [`pd.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas-dataframe-to-csv) does have a `mode` arg, so you could pass `a` or `w`. But yeah, both of these methods are single-directional operators - they don't support arbitrary file read+write or seek operations.

Comment: Thinking it's read *through* pandas may be the issue here. It's *loaded/read* into a pandas dataframe, and from that moment on what you do to the file doesn't affect the dataframe, and visa-versa. Wanting a mode would imply that you think you're either still needing to read the file, or think doing something in pandas should be changing the file. Neither or which are true.